# Can you be surrounded by two persons or things?

Tags: meaning

> In the turbofan engine, the core engine is **surrounded** by a fan in the
> front and an additional turbine at the rear.

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/aturbf.html

The thing is surrounded by two things. One at the rear and another at the front. How does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way of looking at it, a jet engine has one prominent dimension - its length. In that one dimension, it is surrounded. I think that makes sense.

If they had said simply "the core engine has a fan in the front and an additional turbine at the rear", one might think that that the fan and additional turbine were parts of the core engine.

They might have said "is bracketed by...".